Error in my simple php script when i upgrade it from php 7.4 to php 8 i get HTTP ERROR 500
when i upgraded my php script website from php 7.4 to php 8
i get errors "HTTP ERROR 500"
this is at php 8.00
this is at php 7.4
**my index php:
**
<?php
define('INDEX',TRUE);
$bem_cfg = Array();

$bem_cfg['lang'] = Array();

/* current dir aka current app */
$bem_cfg['app_name'] = 'public';

$bem_cfg['app_dir'] = dirname(__FILE__);

require_once $bem_cfg['app_dir'] . '/config.php';

require_once $bem_cfg['app_dir'] . '/app.init.php';

$bem_cfg['tpl_dir'] = './tpl/' . $bem_cfg['cfg_current_template'] ;

require_once $bem_cfg['app_dir'] . '/inc/init.php';

require_once $bem_cfg['lang_dir'] .  '/init.lang.php';

/* init admin menus & modules */
require_once './public.init.php';

$RainTpl->assign('lang',$lang);
$alert = Array();
if(isset($_SESSION['bem_alert'])){
    $alert = $_SESSION['bem_alert'];
    unset($_SESSION['bem_alert']);
}
$RainTpl->assign('alert',$alert);
$RainTpl->assign('locals',$bem_cfg['locals']);

$RainTpl->assign('noMenu',( intval($BemHelpers->getG('nomenu',0)) == 1 ? 1 :0) );



$modPath =  $bem_cfg['mod_dir'] .  '/' . $bem_cfg['app_name'] .
            '/' . $modules[$bem_cfg['app_name']]['main']['class_file_name'];


if( isset( $modules[$bem_cfg['app_name']][($page = $BemHelpers->getG('page','main' ))] ) ) {
    $modPath = $bem_cfg['mod_dir'] . '/' . $bem_cfg['app_name'] . '/' .
     $modules[$bem_cfg['app_name']][$page]['class_file_name'];
}


if( is_file( $modPath ) && file_exists( $modPath ) ) {
    require_once $modPath;
}else{
    $BemHelpers->headers('404');
    die( '<center><span style="font-size:15em">404</span></center>' );
}

if( isset( $CURRENT_MOD_CLASS ) && class_exists( $CURRENT_MOD_CLASS ) ) {
    $currentClass = new $CURRENT_MOD_CLASS( $bem_cfg , $BemHelpers , $BemDB , $RainTpl );
    $currentClass->run();
}else{
    $BemHelpers->headers('404');
    die( '<center><span style="font-size:15em">404</span></center>' );
}





can you help me?
when i get back to php 7.4 or less the website working
but when i upgrade after 7.4 it crashing with HTTP ERROR 500

Turn on PHP error reporting and display/logging to see the true error message

Your server should be logging the error. Please find the server logs, find the error message and the stack trace, edit your question and add both the error message and the stack trace.
